# CSS brainteaser: How do alter last class result in a list

Tags: css

I am displaying search results in a div:

```
<div id="results">
  <div class="list-item">[Text]</div>
  <div class="list-item">[Text]</div>
  <div class="list-item">[Text]</div>
  <div class="list-item">[Text]</div>
  <div class="list-item">[Text]</div>
  <div class="list-item">[Text]</div>
</div>
```

The number of list-items is variable. I want to have `border-bottom: 1px solid #000;` on all the list-item classes, except for the last result. Is there a way in CSS to do this, or do I need to use JS?

Comment: Well, this isn't really a brainteaser... `:last-child` has been around for years.

Comment: It was not at all a brain teaser...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `:not` and `:last-child`:

```
.list-item:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
```

It works and its elegant: http://jsfiddle.net/3Znbu/

Comment: Would give a fiddle link ;) http://jsfiddle.net/xD3dA/

Comment: This is the good way.

Comment: @pzin yes , regards to CSS3 things becomes easier

Answer (score 6):

Use the `:last-child` selector.

```
.list-item {
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}

.list-item:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

As Mooseman pointed out, it won't work on IE8 or less, so if you need IE8 support, I would suggest either a jQuery solution, or using the `:first-child` selector, which has IE7+ support.

**jQuery**

```
$('.list-item:not(:last-child)').css('border-bottom','1px solid #000');
```

**:first-child**

```
.list-item {
  border-top:1px solid #000;
}

.list-item:first-child {
  border-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `:last-child` will not be recognized by IE8: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3

Comment: +1 for `first-child`, but note, that for `:first-child` to work in <= IE8, you must have DOCTYPE specified.

Comment: Frankly if you don't already have a DOCTYPE you shouldn't be trying to use such "advanced" CSS in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

```
#results .list-item:last-child {
   border-bottom: none;
}
```